# getIntent() is returning null and causing NPE

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

ActivityCat has a button with a corresponding method

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityDog.class);
                intent.putExtra(ActivityDog.MY_TIMESTAMP, timestamp);
                startActivity(intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK));
            }
        });
```

But when the button is clicked, I get the following error, which apparently means `getIntent()` is returning null. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.activity.ActivityDog}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:152)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mycompany.myapp.activity.ActivityDog.onCreate(ActivityDog.java:152)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5250)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
    ... 11 more
```

Line 151 and 152 are

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Long myTimestamp = intent.getLongExtra(MY_TIMESTAMP, (Long) null);
```

Comment: I just renamed it right now. Sorry. But no that's not the problem. I will edit.

Answer (score 2):

Change

`Long myTimestamp = intent.getLongExtra(MY_TIMESTAMP, (Long) null);`

to

`Long myTimestamp = intent.getLongExtra(MY_TIMESTAMP, -1);`

...assuming -1 is your default value if no long extra is found. You cannot have a `null` long value.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following fix but I don't like it. It reveals the problem. But is there a more elegant solution?

```
Long myTimestamp = intent.getLongExtra(MY_TIMESTAMP, -1);
myTimestamp = -1 == myTimestamp ? null : myTimestamp;
```

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference, unless the NPE wasn't on the intent.getLongExtra() line you originally indicated.

Comment: The method `getLongExtra()` requires a `long` as its second parameter. You gave it a `null Long`. When it tries to convert(unbox) it, you get an NPE. See [this for more](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-should-i-know-about-autoboxing-and-unboxing-in-java-50/132).

Comment: @Geobits I am not sure, but that case arises if getLongExtra() tries to return the default value passed to it. I believe the key "MY_TIMESTAMP" holds some value and when the OP tries to retrieve it , he is unable to get the same and thus it tries to get the default which is null and then whatever you said becomes applicable. But if there is a value in MY_TIMESTAMP a NPE should not be thrown

Comment: @Alice I don't think that's the way it works. it has to have a `long` to even call `getLongExtra()`, so it has to convert it before it makes the call. The NPE will happen whether the key exists or not, because it never gets that far.